# Orthonormal Preserves Angle Between Vectors

Tags: plotting, manipulate, vector

Consider:

```
U = {{4/5, 3/5}, {3/5, -4/5}};
u1 = {1, 3};
u2 = {-1, 3};
VectorAngle[u1, u2]
VectorAngle[U.u1, U.u2]
```

Which produces this output:

ArcCos[4/5]
ArcCos[4/5]

So, the dot product preserves the angle between two vectors. However, I am having difficulty with this:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Circle[],
   Blue, Thick,
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}],
   Text[Style["x", 12, Bold], 1.1 {Cos[t], Sin[t]}],
   Red,
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, U.{Cos[t], Sin[t]}}],
   Text[Style["U x", 12, Bold], 1.1 U.{Cos[t], Sin[t]}],
   },
  PlotRange -> 1.2,
  Axes -> True
  ], {{t, 0}, 0, 2 π}]
```

Here are two snapshots:

[image]

[image]

The angle between the vectors is not being preserved as I move the slider. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**Update:** Thanks to all the help and MichaelE2's suggestion, I was able to make a better demonstration.

```
DynamicModule[{U},
 U = {{4/5, 3/5}, {3/5, -4/5}};
 Manipulate[Graphics[{
    Circle[{0, 0}, 1],
    Circle[{0, 0}, 1/2],
    Blue, Thick,
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, {.5 Cos[t + phi], .5 Sin[t + phi]}}], 
    Text[Style["x", 12, Bold], 1.1 {Cos[t], Sin[t]}],
    Text[Style["y", 12, Bold], 
     1.1 {.5 Cos[t + phi], .5 Sin[t + phi]}], Red,
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, U.{Cos[t], Sin[t]}}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, U.{.5 Cos[t + phi], .5 Sin[t + phi]}}], 
    Text[Style["U x", 12, Bold], 1.12 U.{Cos[t], Sin[t]}],
    Text[Style["U y", 12, Bold], 
     1.2 U.{.5 Cos[t + phi], .5 Sin[t + phi]}],
    },
   PlotRange -> 1.2, Axes -> True],
  {{t, Pi/4}, 0, 2 π, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{phi, Pi/4}, 0, Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
  ]]
```

[image]

Comment: You have a minus sign in the wrong spot in `U`? Try `U=RotationMatrix[ArcSin[3/5]]`

Comment: Your U has a Det that's -1 and hence is not a rotation matrix. As a consequence, `VectorAngles` does not work for all cases, for instance: u1 = {Sin[0.1], Cos[0.1]} and u2 = {Sin[1], Cos[1]}

Comment: You apply `U` to two vectors in your intro example, but only to one vector in your `Manipulate`.  You need to plot an `x` and a `y`, and then `U.x` and `U.y` to demonstrate preservation of angles.

Comment: You are comparing wrong vectors.

Comment: @bills it's a rotation + inversion. It doesn't change angle between any two vectors.